# access an instance method of a class from another module's instance method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a class which declares a number of instance methods

```
class User < Group
  def get_name

  end

  def show_profile

  end

  def get_task(task_id)
    #some logic
  end

end
```

And I want to call some of these methods from within a module. I can do it with Include statement.

include Users brings in all of the methods from User class. In this case I only want get_task and explicitly do not want get_name, show_profile etc..

I have a Tasks module which also has set of methods and one of those methods calls get_task method of User class.

```
    module Tasks
      class Project
        def design
          tid = 12
          design_task = get_task(tid)
        end
      end
   end
```

How this can be achieved without including other unnecessary methods of that class. Please help.

Comment: You don't include a class, you include a module. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: Yes.. You are right. Sorry.. What I want to achieve is to call get_task method from module Tasks::Project#design method.. I am sorry. Just starting to learn ruby metaprogramming. So came up with this kind of scenario.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, your code was correct for module Task, now it's not. My comment was on your these lines: *include Users brings in all of the methods from User class. In this case I only want get_task and explicitly do not want get_name, show_profile etc..*

Comment: I am trying to understand the code from one of the application. It codes like the above. module Tasks;end and then declare class. So far I have seen only like the one which I used to code module Tasks class Project end end. I am not sure what difference it makes with the previous one.

Comment: `module Tasks;end` means that you have ended scope of module Task right after creating it. So, class Project can not be accessed as: `Task::Project` like you have posted in your previous comment. That's the difference it makes between first and new change.

Comment: Yes.. I was also thinking the same way.. But I was told by one of the developer that it is used for namespacing also. Anyways so if thats the case, as per the above code, is there any way I can access get_task method from that module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63280/discussion-between-rubyist-and-surya).

Answer (score 0):

If the get_task method isn't depending on the user, you can use a class method like below. If it is depending on the user, you will have to get the server before you can run the method.

```
class User < Group
    def get_name

    end

    def show_profile

    end

    def self.get_task(task_id)
    #some logic
    end

end

class Project
    def design
        tid = 12
        design_task = User.get_task(tid)
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry. I didnt get that statement "If it is depending on the user, you will have to get the server before you can run the method"

Comment: If you want the "get_task" method to do something to a instance of the user you will need to get the user first, then call user_variable.get_task(tid). If the method isn't doing anything to a specific instance of a user, you can use a class variable.